# Why Excel custom cell format have a duplicate "-" symbole?

Tags: excel, format

I want to use custom format that respect thoses rules :

```
if the value is between ]100,-100[ return "-"
if the value is negative return -# ##0,0 "M€"
if the value is positive reutrn # ##0,0 "M€"
```

I tried to use this format `[>=100]# ##0,0 "M€";[<=-100]-# ##0,0 "M€";"-"`.

But it doesn't work at all because when I use those numbers it give me :

```
29000 -> 29,0M€
-29000 -> -29,0M€
29 -> -
-29 -> --
0 -> -
```

Here's what I want :

```
29000 -> 29,0M€
-29000 -> -29,0M€
29 -> -
-29 -> -
0 -> -
```

Why is it returning "--" instead of "-" ?

Comment: Your third section is basically an 'any other number' section, and there is no way to suppress the negative symbol for those. Use condtional formatting instead.

Comment: is it possible to skip the 'any other number' section and redirect the result to a string that is "-" ?

Comment: No it is not. Use CF.